# Sklearn GridSearchCV Produce very differet numbers for test_score and train_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, data-science, grid-search

I have been running GridSearchCV to find the best hyperparameters for my regression ANN. However, I find it hard to interpret the test_score and train_score values and why they are so unreasonably different.

The ANN is created with Keras and MSE is used as loss.

If I set the parameter cv=10 the results are reasonable, but when I use cv=3 it is not reasonable and not comparable to if I would do a regular split into test/train sets and run it manually (MSE would be much smaller then).

Results for cv=10.

```
{'mean_fit_time': array([ 45.64931359]),
 'mean_score_time': array([ 0.88778265]),
 'mean_test_score': array([-80.58573808]),
 'mean_train_score': array([-54.32416867]),
 'param_batch_size': masked_array(data = [25],
              mask = [False],
        fill_value = ?),
 'param_epochs': masked_array(data = [500],
              mask = [False],
        fill_value = ?),
 'params': [{'batch_size': 25, 'epochs': 500}],
 'rank_test_score': array([1]),
 'split0_test_score': array([-79.8304968]),
 'split0_train_score': array([-54.1543676]),
 'split1_test_score': array([-88.66814966]),
 'split1_train_score': array([-52.53867387]),
 'split2_test_score': array([-72.68088307]),
 'split2_train_score': array([-54.22193575]),
 'split3_test_score': array([-65.62303455]),
 'split3_train_score': array([-55.11768506]),
 'split4_test_score': array([-91.78870671]),
 'split4_train_score': array([-53.60385677]),
 'split5_test_score': array([-69.70716374]),
 'split5_train_score': array([-54.90494821]),
 'split6_test_score': array([-72.369327]),
 'split6_train_score': array([-55.06327332]),
 'split7_test_score': array([-63.47190503]),
 'split7_train_score': array([-57.14306102]),
 'split8_test_score': array([-61.61434507]),
 'split8_train_score': array([-56.35855999]),
 'split9_test_score': array([-139.97252682]),
 'split9_train_score': array([-50.13532509]),
 'std_fit_time': array([ 4.63885948]),
 'std_score_time': array([ 0.36701861]),
 'std_test_score': array([ 21.97077353]),
 'std_train_score': array([ 1.86790488])}
```

If I instead use cv=3 I get extremely large numbers for the test_score but not the train_score.

```
 'params': [{'batch_size': 25, 'epochs': 500}],
 'rank_test_score': array([1]),
 'split0_test_score': array([-9366.9518699]),
 'split0_train_score': array([-47.92415035]),
 'split1_test_score': array([-9379.17264271]),
 'split1_train_score': array([-51.44866994]),
 'split2_test_score': array([-9065.89809108]),
 'split2_train_score': array([-49.70452372]),
 'std_fit_time': array([ 1.89022517]),
 'std_score_time': array([ 0.08712083]),
 'std_test_score': array([ 144.81240151]),
 'std_train_score': array([ 1.43890443])}
```

Full script:

```
#Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import random

#Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', encoding="latin-1", sep=",")

X = dataset.loc[:, (dataset.columns !='Visitors') & (dataset.columns !='X') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Unnamed: 0') & (dataset.columns != 'Empty Spot') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Date') & (dataset.columns != 'Empty Spot')].values

Y = dataset.loc[:, (dataset.columns !='X') &
                (dataset.columns !='Empty spot') & (dataset.columns !='Logi.total') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Rain.mm') & (dataset.columns != 'Lufttryck') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Unnamed: 0') & (dataset.columns != 'Day') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Month') & (dataset.columns != 'Week.day') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Week.number') & (dataset.columns != 'Year') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Temp18') & (dataset.columns != 'Rain') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Cloud') & (dataset.columns != 'utan_regn') & (dataset.columns != 'Vindstyrka') &
                (dataset.columns != 'med_regn') & (dataset.columns != 'SMA') & (dataset.columns !='Date') &
                (dataset.columns != 'Temp06') & (dataset.columns != 'Empty spot')].values

#Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
X[:, 8] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 8])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

#Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
Scaler_X = StandardScaler()
X = Scaler_X.fit_transform(X)

#Buidling the ANN
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def HO():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(73, kernel_initializer = 'normal', activation='linear', 
    input_dim=73))
    model.add(Dense(35, kernel_initializer = 'normal',activation='linear'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'normal'))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

    return model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn = HO, verbose = 1)

# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [25]
epochs = [500]

param_grid = dict(batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)

# cv=3 or cv=10 in my examples
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3) 
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, 
grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Why is the test_score calculated so differently compared to the train_score if I use less folds? I also get unreasonably high error with cv=2, cv=5 etc.

Comment: Can you share your `dataset.csv`?

Comment: Yes, more information about the data would be needed. Is it a time series?

Comment: The dataset has the following independent variables (X) that are used as input:

Week.day -   Categorical.
Day - Integer.
Month  - Categorical.
Week.number  -  Categorical.
Year - Categorical.
Logi.total  - Number of booked tickets.
Temp06  - Temperature at 06:00.
Temp18   - Temperature at 18:00.
Rain  - Did it rain yes/no.
med_regn  - number of previous days with rain.
utan_regn - number of previous days without rain.
Rain.mm  - Rain in mm.
Cloud  - Amount of cloud, number.
Lufttryck  - air pressure.
Vindstyrka  - wind strength.
SMA - 4 day moving average number of visitors.

Comment: The purpose is to create a ANN That predicts the number of visitors to a theme park. So the dependent variable is "Visitors".

With categorical transformations I have 73 input variables. The number of input variables was 16 before that.

Additionally. Visitors (number of visitors) is transformed with ^(1/2) to make it nore normally distributed (which gave better results when experimenting).

Comment: The first row.
Week day: Saturday
Day: 22
Month: 5
Week number: 20
Year: 2010
Logi total: 0
Temp06: 14.9
Temp18: 19.6
Rain: Yes
med_regn: 1
utan_regn: 0
Rain.mm: 0.9
Cloud: 62.1
Lufttryck: 1022.6
Vindstyrka: 1
SMA: 6353

DV (Visitors): 25.593

Comment: The dataset has 562 rows.

Comment: Can you try to shuffle your data beforehand? `from sklearn.utils import shuffle; X, y = shuffle(X, y)`

Comment: Looks like this is a time-series. So the normal cross-validation iteration used in GridSearchCV will not work. You need to use [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)